# Using torch.lstm rises nans unless I initialize it every iteration

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, nan

I try to use `torch.nn.lstm` to predict future retail prices. My data cover different stores over time. In each iteration I draw `batch_size` of 2 stores, then I train my LSTM sequentially over the periods which are covered in the data.
My problem is this - in each iteration I create a `month X 2-stores` dataset (for the sake of this post), and run it through the model.
Before I start, I initialize it using the `init` function. In that case, the resulting tensor is full of `nans`. On the other hand, if I'm using `init` every time, the results are actual numbers.
The lstm model is

```py
n_features = 68
n_steps = 3
batch_size = 2
seq_len = n_steps*batch_size
n_hidden = 2 # number of hidden states
n_layers = 2 # number of LSTM layers (stacked)

# 2. Build the Model
class SmallLSTM(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_features,seq_len, n_hidden, n_layers, n_steps, batch_size):
        super(SmallLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.n_features = n_features
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.n_hidden = n_hidden # number of hidden states
        self.n_layers = n_layers # number of LSTM layers (stacked)
        self.n_steps = n_steps 
        self.batch_size = batch_size 
        
        self.l_lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size = self.n_features, 
                       hidden_size = self.n_hidden,
                       num_layers = self.n_layers, 
                       batch_first = True,
                       dropout = 0.1)
        # according to pytorch docs LSTM output is 
        # (batch_size,seq_len, num_directions * hidden_size)
        # when considering batch_first = True
        self.l_linear = torch.nn.Linear(self.n_steps*self.batch_size * self.n_hidden, self.batch_size)

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        # even with batch_first = True this remains same as docs
        hidden_state = torch.zeros(self.n_layers,1,self.n_hidden)
        cell_state = torch.zeros(self.n_layers,1,self.n_hidden)
        self.hidden = (hidden_state, cell_state)
    
    def forward(self, x):        
        #batch_size, seq_len, _ = x.size()
        
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.l_lstm(x,self.hidden)
        # lstm_out(with batch_first = True) is 
        # (batch_size,seq_len,num_directions * hidden_size)
        # for following linear layer we want to keep batch_size dimension and merge rest       
        # .contiguous() -> solves tensor compatibility error
        lstm_out = lstm_out.reshape((1,self.n_steps*self.batch_size * self.n_hidden))
        lstm_out = self.l_linear(lstm_out)
        
        #self.hidden = [elem.detach_() for elem in self.hidden]

        return lstm_out
```

Without the per-iteration initialization the code looks like that

```py
batch_size = 2
stores_drawn_idx = 2
Stores_train_batch = Stores_train.iloc[stores_drawn_idx:stores_drawn_idx+batch_size]
Stores_train_batch.reset_index(inplace=True, drop = True)
stores_drawn_idx += batch_size
Months = Xy['Month'].sort_values().unique()
n_steps = 3


mv_net = SmallLSTM(n_features = n_features,\
                    seq_len = seq_len, \
                    n_hidden=n_hidden, \
                    n_layers = n_layers, \
                    n_steps = n_steps, \
                    batch_size = batch_size)
mv_net.init_hidden(1)


train_batch = pd.DataFrame(columns = Xy.columns)
for j in range(Stores_train_batch.shape[0]):
  X_ = Xy_temp_month.drop(['origin_address', 'Retailer_origin', 'Month', 'target'], axis = 1).values.astype('float32')
  y_ = Xy_temp_month[Xy_temp_month['Month'] == months_temp[-1]]['target']

  X_ = torch.from_numpy(X_.reshape(1,n_steps*batch_size,X_.shape[1]))
  X_ = torch.tensor(X_,dtype=torch.float32)
  y_ = torch.tensor(y_.values.astype('float32'), dtype=torch.float32).reshape([len(y_)])

  n_features = 68
  seq_len = n_steps*batch_size
  n_hidden = 2 # number of hidden states
  n_layers = 2 # number of LSTM layers (stacked)

  criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(mv_net.parameters(), lr=0.05, weight_decay=1500)
  valid_loss_min = 1000

  #mv_net.init_hidden(1)
  output = mv_net(X_)

  loss = criterion(output, y_)
  print(loss.item())
```

Under this scenario the results are `nan` for each time the line `print(loss.item())` runs.
If I add that line `mv_net.init_hidden(1)` I get values for the loss.

What should I do?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you confirm that `self.hidden` is generated correctly in `forward()` and has the type that you expect? One common source of `nan` errors is a type mismatch in pytorch.

Comment: Also, why do you redefine the optimizer and loss function at every iteration? This seems likely to cause errors since Adam maintains some running-average parameters across iterations